# Modifying the get_avatar() function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, avatar, gravatar

I found a great tutorial to create a custom avatar (https://www.billerickson.net/wordpress-custom-avatar/). Basically it checks:

1) If there’s a custom avatar, use that.

2) If there isn’t a custom avatar, check to see if there’s a gravatar. If there’s a gravatar, use that.

3) If there’s neither, display the default.

The issue is that I have registered users on my wordpress, so whenever they comment, it uses the custom avatar I've set for the author, for all the commentors who have an email registered.

This is the part of the code I'm struggling with:

```
// If provided an email and it doesn't exist as WP user, return avatar since there can't be a custom avatar
$email = is_object( $id_or_email ) ? $id_or_email->comment_author_email : $id_or_email;
if( is_email( $email ) && ! email_exists( $email ) )
    return $avatar;

$custom_avatar = get_the_author_meta('be_custom_avatar');
if ($custom_avatar) 
    $return = '<img src="'.$custom_avatar.'" width="'.$size.'" height="'.$size.'" alt="'.$alt.'" />';
elseif ($avatar) 
    $return = $avatar;
else 
    $return = '<img src="'.$default.'" width="'.$size.'" height="'.$size.'" alt="'.$alt.'" />';
return $return;
```

How can I make it check so that if the "be_custom_avatar" is empty in the Users Profile, and they have no gravatar set, it returns the default wordpress $avatar ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Add your own avatar in WordPress**

```html
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'custom_avatar' );
    function custom_avatar($avatar_defaults){
    $custom_avatar = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/default-avatar.jpg';
    $avatar_defaults[$custom_avatar] = "My Default Avatar";
    return $avatar_defaults;
 }
```

Try this code, you get the solution

Comment: That's the same code as this tutorial (https://www.wpstuffs.com/how-to-display-custom-avatar-in-comments-for-users-without-gravatar/). This solves the ability to add a custom avatar but it doesn't accomplish the task of:

1) Allowing for a custom gravatar per author user profile.
2) Checking if the user has a locally hosted avatar and if not, checking if they have a gravatar and if there's none set, using the custom avatar.